# My HTML code changed?

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

I recently made a website using Brackets. It was working and after a while I took it down, but now when I'm looking at my code, it has totally changed. I'm not sure how to explain this. After I uploaded my website to my domain, the code actually changed, and all of my images were removed from the HTML, and now it just looks like a plain document. Here is my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/css/theme.css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1404.46">
  <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 14.0px; font: 12.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}
    p.p3 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 14.0px; font: 12.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000; min-height: 14.0px}
    p.p5 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 12.0px 0.0px; line-height: 14.0px; font: 12.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}
    p.p7 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 12.0px 0.0px; line-height: 14.0px; font: 12.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000; min-height: 14.0px}
    p.p9 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 13.0px; font: 11.0px '.AppleSystemUIFont'; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}
    li.li2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 14.0px; font: 12.0px Times; color: #0000ee; -webkit-text-stroke: #0000ee}
    span.s1 {font-kerning: none}
    span.s2 {-webkit-text-stroke: 0px #000000}
    span.s3 {text-decoration: underline ; font-kerning: none}
    span.s4 {font-kerning: none; color: #0000ee; -webkit-text-stroke: 0px #0000ee}
    span.s5 {font-kerning: none; background-color: #c0c0c0}
    span.s6 {font: 12.0px Times; font-kerning: none}
    ul.ul1 {list-style-type: disc}
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span></p>
<ul class="ul1">
  <li class="li2"><span class="s2"></span><span class="s3">What we do</span></li>
  <li class="li2"><span class="s2"></span><span class="s3">Our process<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></li>
  <li class="li2"><span class="s2"></span><span class="s3">Our team<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></li>
  <li class="li2"><span class="s2"></span><span class="s3">Contact us</span></li>
</ul>
<p class="p3"><span class="s1"></span><br></p>
<h1 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 16.1px 0.0px; line-height: 28.0px; font: 24.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Change The Way You Pay<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></b></span></h1>
<p class="p5"><span class="s1">With Tip Me, you will be able to make transactions like never before</span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span></p>
<h2 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 14.9px 0.0px; line-height: 22.0px; font: 18.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Tip Anyone. Anytime. Anywhere.<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></b></span></h2>
<p class="p5"><span class="s1">No need to pull out your wallet anymore. With Tip Me, you will be able to make simple, efficient transactions with the click of a button.<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span></p>
<h2 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 14.9px 0.0px; line-height: 22.0px; font: 18.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Efficiently Manage Your Money<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></b></span></h2>
<p class="p5"><span class="s1">Never lose track of your transactions. You will be able to view who has tipped you, whom you have tipped, and how much was exchanged.</span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span></p>
<h2 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 14.9px 0.0px; line-height: 22.0px; font: 18.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Make Secure Transactions<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></b></span></h2>
<p class="p5"><span class="s1">Never worry about securing confidential information again. Through Tip Me, all user payments are Level 1 PCI compliance encrypted.</span></p>
<p class="p7"><span class="s1"></span><br></p>
<h1 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 16.1px 0.0px; line-height: 28.0px; font: 24.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Our Process<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></b></span></h1>
<p class="p5"><span class="s1">Select a friend, enter an amount, and tip. Yes, it's that simple.<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<h1 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 16.1px 0.0px; line-height: 28.0px; font: 24.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Our Team<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></b></span></h1>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span></p>
<h2 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 14.9px 0.0px; line-height: 22.0px; font: 18.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Nilay Neeranjun<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></b></span></h2>
<p class="p5"><span class="s1">Co-Founder, Software Developer</span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s4"><a href="file:///Users/nneeranjun/Desktop/Tip%20Me%20Website/www.linkedin.com/in/nilay-neeranjun"></a></span><span class="s1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"></span></p>
<h2 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 14.9px 0.0px; line-height: 22.0px; font: 18.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Badri Narayan</b></span></h2>
<p class="p5"><span class="s1">Co-Founder, Software Developer</span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s4"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/badrinnarayan"></a></span><span class="s1"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<h1 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 14.9px 0.0px; line-height: 22.0px; font: 18.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Contact Us</b></span></h1>
<h4 style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 16.0px 0.0px; line-height: 14.0px; font: 12.0px Times; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000"><span class="s1"><b>Send us a message and we will get back to you as soon as possible</b></span></h4>
<p class="p7"><span class="s1"></span><br></p>
<p class="p7"><span class="s1"></span><br></p>
<p class="p7"><span class="s1"></span><br></p>
<p class="p7"><span class="s1"></span><br></p>
<p class="p3"><span class="s1"></span><br></p>
<p class="p3"><span class="s1"></span><br></p>
<p class="p9"><span class="s5">Submit</span><span class="s6"><span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Copyright © TipMe 2015<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

There used to be links for my CSS and now there is CSS within the HTML which was never there before. I am very confused as to what happened to my actual code after I uploaded it and how I can get it back. Sorry if this is really confusing but I have no idea what has happened

Comment: was your site hosted previously ? Do you hosting company provide backup ?

Comment: Right now I have a website I am currently working on, on my domain. Its (http://tipmeapp.co). I took my original website down so that I can test this new one out, but now my whole code seems to have changed. I can't link the website but I could send you my whole folder of files from my website if that would help